# PayPal subscription package trial setting

Tags: paypal, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

In our website user can sign up with different subscription packages with some days trial version using PayPal.

Can we change trial days after creating subscription in PayPal? We have mistakenly set weeks instead of days. We want to change it back to days. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Subscriptions API, you can make changes, but the subscriber must approve those changes for them to take effect.

Since they must give their approval anyway, if you don't know what you are doing you may find it easier to have them cancel their existing subscription and sign up for a correct one.